# How do you split export of large query result to multiple CSVs in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, export, workbench

Is there a way to efficiently split a large query result over excels max row limit (1,048,576) automatically on export in MySQL Workbench?

I see it's possible to do this with MySQLDump, but is there are way to do this without writing results to a table and then exporting that table?

On export I would like results over 1,000,000 lines to split at line 1,000,000 and create a new file with remaining results.

I could possibly split files post export, but would like to see if it's possible to have this done on export to reduce number of steps.

Comment: Add a limit to the first query and a limit and an Offset and rowcount to the second and subsequent queries

Comment: write a stored procedure that wil run  Riggs code in a loop with dynamic sql